# Drush migrate can't find database

Tags: drush, acquia-dev-desktop

I am running a local Drupal 8 site via Aquia DevDesktop. I enabled the Migrate modules: Migrate, Migrate Drupal, Migrate Drupal IU, Migrate Plus and Migrate Tools. When I run a migrate command in drush, such as migrate-status, I get an error, "unknown database".  Settings.php is correct and the site if working fine. I am running drush 8.1.17 and other drush commands work ok. Any suggestions?

[image: drush migrate-status error message]

Comment: My suggestion is to check which mysql Drush is trying to use. The one on your local machine. Or the one in Dev Desktop?

Comment: Do other drush commands work? There is a database connection loop created with dev desktop